"Танечниця" чи "танцюристка"?
У чому різниця між "танечниця" та "танцюристка" -- неначе синоніми... Англійською обидва -- "dancer".

Perše — zastarêle. Ce poznačeno i v slovnıkax.

Якось не схоже це на застарілість :-)

Ce xudožnjıj tvôr, kotrıj možeʼ matı arxajizmı [naprıklad perekladı serijı Vêdjmaka, Hrı prestolôv povni na arxajizmı, a vžıv ne robeʼ jıx znovu sučasnımı] i ne duže vêdomıj [pôd 2 tıs. perehljadôv] i de v komentax zaznačajutj na «Танечниця... яке чудернацьке слово, вперше чую», i jedınıj prıklad.

Перший синонім (танечниця) в сучасній мові не застосовується взагалі — ані в усній, ані у письмовій. Більше того: припускаю, що не кожен навіть зрозуміє Вас, якщо Ви будете це слово вживати. Зізнаюся, я й сам навіть не чув цього слова ніколи аж до того, як побачив Ваше запитання.
В сучасній мові вживаються слова танцюристка та танцівниця, але не танечниця.

Я й сам не чув, але, коли натрапив на цю пісню, то одразу ж зрозумів, про що йдеться... Ну, гаразд, застарілий так застарілий... А в чому, до речі, різниця між "танцюристкою" та "танцівницею"?

@MikhailT. ТАНЦІВНИК, а, ч . Те саме, що танцюрист.
